# Calculating a stochastic differential

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $f$ be a real-valued function with bounded continuous second derivative $f''$, and $w(t)$ be a Wiener process.  Let $$ V(t,w(t)) = f(w(t)) - \frac{1}{2} \int_a^t f''(w(s))ds. $$

I want to apply I want to apply the following formula

$$dV(t,w(t)) = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}V(t,w(t)) + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}V(t,w(t))\right)dt  + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}V(t,w(t))dw(t)$$ to find the differential of $V(t,w(t))$.

Comment: do you want to apply ito 's formula ?

Comment: It is not $x$ its $W_t$ or $w(t)$ in your terminology

Comment: @daryakhosrotash I want to apply the formula given

Comment: Main problem: the RHS defining your $V(t,w(t))$ is *not* a function of $t$ and $w(t)$ (but of the whole past $(w(s))_{s\leqslant t}$). Hence, no Itô directly on $V(t,w(t))$. Fortunately, the first part $f(w(t))$ is a function of $w(t)$ hence Itô applies, and the differential of the second part is trivially $-\frac12f''(w(t))dt$.